Proving the Conditional Markov's Inequality
I am trying to prove the conditional Markov's Inequality, which states:
For a non-negative random variable $X$ and constant $a \geq 0$,
$$P(X>a|Y) \leq \frac{E[X|Y]}{a} \text{ a.s. (almost surely)}$$
I have claimed and proven the two following statements:
\begin{align*}
\text{(A). }& P(X>a|Y) \leq E\left[\frac X a|Y\right] \text{a.s.}\\
\text{(B). }&E\left[\frac X a|Y\right] = \frac{E[X|Y]}{a} \text{a.s.}
\end{align*}
Please note  that statements A and B refer to their respective equation without the "almost surely."
By definition of almost surely, $P(A)= P(B)=1$. My approach was to prove $P(A \cap B)= 1$, which, by definition, implies the Markov's inequality (I've attached the proof of this below).
Is this approach correct? Is this the general way to prove the "transitivity of almost surely"? Is there another way to prove it?
P.S.:
I'm not sure what property of almost surely this is, hence the double bracket "transitivity of almost surely." My apologies for the butchering of proper terminology.

Claim: $P(A \cap B)=1$
Proof:
By the inclusion-exclusion formula,
\begin{align*}
    P(A \cap B) &= P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cup B) \\
      &= 1 + 1 - P(A \cup B)\\
&= 2 - P(A \cup B)
\end{align*}

Note that $P(A \cup B) \in [0,1] \implies P(A\cap B) \in [1,2]$.
However, by law of probability, $P(A \cap B) \leq 1$, thus $P(A \cap B) = 1$. This completes the proof.


You are correct as far as I can see.
You could express "almost surely" as
"there exists $N_A$ with $A^c \subset N_A$ and $P(N_A)=0$" instead (where $A^c$ denotes the complement of $A$) and then if $A$ and $B$ hold almost surely, you have $(A \cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c \subset N_A \cup N_B$ and you have
$$P(N_A \cup N_B) \le P(N_B) + P(N_B) = 0.$$
This proof is equivalent to your proof, but it also works for any measure space (with "almost surely" replaced by "almost everywhere") and $A$ and $B$ by any subsets of the space. If you don't care about these details, you could define "almost surely $Z$" for an event $Z$ as $P(Z^c) = 0$ and then just write your proof as
$$0 \le P((A\cap B)^c) = P(A^c \cup B^c) \le P(A^c) + P(B^c) = 0$$
which avoids having to invoke that $P$ is a probability measure but is otherwise the same as what you did.
